# Informational security model models and life-cycle

Tags: threat-modeling, content-security-policy

NSM model from sans.org is vendor neutral,that's good, but I need more detail and complexity model. Don't want to invent a bicycle and looking for complete solution in this field.Looking not for blog article or "startup-theory" , but for good designed document with good segments and theme coverage and life-cycle(is a must ).

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your question. We do try to keep questions limited to one question only. Could you either split this into two questions or decide if they're closely related enough to be one question?